# Very high latency on simple GET requests

Tags: python, api, web-services, nginx, uwsgi

I wrote a very simple flask web service that simply returns text `hey23` upon being hit and hosted on AWS EC2 t2.micro machine (1GB RAM 1CPU)

To execute this python application I used uwsgi as my app server. Finally I've put my complete setup behind Nginx.

So my stack is `Flask+uwsgi+Nginx`

Everything is working fine and good. I only have complaint with the execution time. The average latency measured using [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) is ~370ms, which is too much considering the amount of work this service is doing.

```
Running 30s test @ http://XX.XXX.XX.XX/printtest
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   370.98ms  178.90ms   1.96s    91.78%
    Req/Sec    93.72     36.72   270.00     69.55%
  33124 requests in 30.11s, 5.41MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 15
  Non-2xx or 3xx responses: 1173
Requests/sec:   1100.26
Transfer/sec:    184.14KB
```

hello-test.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/print23")
def helloprint():
    return "hey23"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, threaded=True)
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /var/www/demoapp
master = true

#python module to import
app = hello-test
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /var/www/demoapp/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 644

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
callable = app
disable-logging = True

#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
max-worker-lifetime = 30

processes = 10
threads = 2
enable-threads = True
cheaper = 2
cheaper-initial = 5
cheaper-step = 1

cheaper-algo = spare
cheaper-overload = 5
```

Even if i forget about wrk benchmark, even with posting GET requests from my [POSTMAN client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), I am getting similar latency.

What is wrong here? No matter what, some takeaways

1. Code cannot be optimised. It just has to return `hey23` string.
   Nothing can be wrong with Nginx.
2. I certainly assume ~370ms is not a
   good response time for an API doing such a simple task.
3. Changing the region in which my EC2 machine is hosted may bring some change, but common, this should not be sole reason.

Then what am i missing?

Comment: `~370ms` - its for request netto or its for request + response?

Comment: @sKwa: I suppose it should be request + response. How can request alone  makes sense?

Comment: can you post last line of `ping -c5 <host>` also? (request only - to avoid network/connectivity issues)

Comment: this is what I have got `ping -c5 XX.XXX.XX.XX
PING XX.XXX.XX.XX (XX.XXX.XX.XX): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3

--- XX.XXX.XX.XX ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss`

Comment: Sorry please ignore last output.
Remote execution -->
`5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 294.168/348.128/401.396/45.619 ms`



`From machine itself` -->
`5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.517/0.582/0.620/0.046 ms`

Comment: looks like connectivity issue. remote ping avg -> 348.128ms, request avg -> 370.98ms.